# Conversion of unsigned long to std::vector with memcpy, endian?

Tags: c++, vector, int, endianness, unsigned

Well i'm trying to convert a unsigned long into char vector.

```
std::vector<char> out(1024);
while(n < length) 
{
    for(int = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
    //code...
    unsigned long v0 = 0x9514a327;
    //code...
    }
memcpy( &out[n], &v0, sizeof( v0 ) );
}
```

out gets dynamically filled within the while-loop (out stores the values of v0). My problem is, that the order has changed to:

```
out[0] = 0x27
out[1] = 0xa3
out[2] = 0x14
out[3] = 0x95
```

But i need:

```
out[0] = 0x95
out[1] = 0x14
out[2] = 0xa3
out[3] = 0x27
```

How can i fix this i a elegant way?

Comment: Your code won't compile, `v0` used outside its scope.

Comment: Your problem is called endianess. You could use `htons` to convert your value to big-endian prior to memcpy (which is what you need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's late and I didn't test it but should give you an idea

```
v0 = ((v0 & 0xFF) << 24) | ((v0 & 0xFF00) << 8) | ((v0 & 0xFF0000) >> 8) | ((v0 & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
```

Answer (score 2):

The elegant and faster way is avoiding `memcpy()` and directly assigning the bytes from your `long` with bit-shifting. You get the same `char`-array independent of host endianness even!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int n = sizeof v0; n--; )
{
    out[n] = v0 % 0x100;
    v0 /= 0x100;
}
```

You can trade performance (possibly) for elegance by unrolling this loop. I hide it all behind an inline function in my own code.